# Type not resolved when using Exclude and this type

Tags: typescript

Typescript is not resolving type correctly, when using `Exclude` with `this` reference in abstract class.

Consider following code

```
abstract class abstr {
  abstract readonly A: Readonly<string[]>;
  abstract readonly B: Readonly<string[]>;

  abstract readonly onlyA: this['A'][number];
  abstract readonly onlyB: this['B'][number];

  abstract readonly AorB: this['A'][number] | this['B'][number];
  abstract readonly AnotB: Exclude<this['A'][number], this['B'][number]>;
}

class impl extends abstr {
  readonly A = ['x', 'y', 'z'] as const;
  readonly B = ['w', 'q', 'z'] as const;

  readonly onlyA = 'x';     // typeof super.onlyA = 'x' | 'y' | 'z'; // CORRECT
  readonly onlyB = 'w';     // typeof super.onlyB = 'w' | 'q' | 'z'; // CORRECT

  readonly AorB = 'y';  // typeof super.AorB = 'x' | 'y' | 'z' | 'w' | 'q'; // CORRECT
  readonly AnotB = 'x'; // typeof super.AnotB = ???; expected 'x' | 'y' // WRONG
}
```

In the implementing class, types of `onlyA`, `onlyB` and `AorB` are correctly resolved and type checked, but not `AnotB`. `AnotB` should be resolved to type `'x' | 'y'`, but looks like it is not resolved at all. Can't assign anything to it...

Is there an explanation? Is it a bug? Any possible workaround to achieve the intended type checking in derived class?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjA0koIN4CgFNxo5EoBTYAEwHsA7ZATwQEEAuBAJSrsaYA82AJb0A5gG0AugD4A3IWLYyCSjQbMEAIU491-IdFGTZCxVlLxVvDS1scEEABbCwEgOSt3UifQCuALYgFFBSCkQWMFZqfJq2Oo4ubu5a3r6BwaFmESRR5Db8bLRQCc6uHl4+-kEhUggAPonlKWnVmWHmuSoxtmz0tBAJAKIAHih+1BQCZcmV6TWhADRNyalVGbXy+AC++PgoaBjCAQAOyAgUIxAU9NQYkXiKPYWsCAC8CB4j7svuTD8IdwAL28mAwsAYkHC1n0mi070+7gA7gD3ABHVEgupoJCQiDZGGxOz8V4fdzfOREKkAempjiYJwotAAZggwH5GVAAHT2BHk9wNQH-QXA9yU2kIADCAHkuFwhpKACpPApxfjwskoylUhASiAMpms9mcnnqvkokUYkUg8V0mVyhXKlWwlisYoaoVioh6g0stkckJct0lPnfEXCxqikUWyMY21S2XypXOol9AYe-nx-WMv3GwOsfqDBEAflLlMujPgFGogLDkeFEoA6lxpQA5ADiO3wQA)

Comment: That's great question, following

Comment: Need generics: https://tsplay.dev/m33yym - since TypeScript doesn't try to evaluate or compute what the types are.

Comment: Almost any time `this` is resolved inside a class body, it's done *prematurely* for convenience and thus has the potential to be incorrect.  On the other hand, when `this` is *not* resolved, then the type is inconvenient to use.  Subclasses can always narrow property types, see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXzKQm) for why resolving is problematic.  You should just use an assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOxPRN) if you want to keep it as-is.  Otherwise I'd say refactor to use a factory function like maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL5l2W).

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the comment/answer Actually my main question / problem is to understand why adding ```Exclude``` changes the order of resolution. Why does it work without ```Exclude``` and why not when using ```Exclude```? Is this behaviour somewhere documented?

The workarounds you presented are basically clear and known, just don't like them very much - they all introduce some "unneeded" overhead...

Re subclasses narrowing properties (your first playground) - imo correct behaviour in such case would be "Error: class Impl2 wrongly implements class Impl1"